# System.MissingMemberException was unhandled by user code

Tags: vb.net, linq, binding, telerik

I'm using this code:

```
Dim VehiclesTable1 = dsVehicleList.Tables(0)
Dim VT1 = (From d In VehiclesTable1.AsEnumerable _
          Select VehicleTypeName = d.Item("VehicleTypeName") _
                 , VTypeID = d.Item("VTypeID") _
                 , ImageURL = d.Item("ImageURL") _
                 , DailyRate = d.Item("DailyRate") _
                 , RateID = d.Item("RateID")).Distinct
```

its linq to dataset

and I Take Data on THis Rotator:

```
<telerik:RadRotator ID="RadRotatorVehicleType" runat="server" Width="620px" Height="145"
                                                                            ItemWidth="155" ItemHeight="145" ScrollDirection="Left" FrameDuration="1" RotatorType="Buttons">
                                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                                <div style="text-align: center; cursor: pointer; width: 150px">
                                                                                    <asp:Image ID="ImageVehicleType" runat="server" Width="150" ImageUrl='<%# Container.DataItem("ImageURL") %>' />
                                                                                    <asp:Label ID="lblVehicleType" runat="server" Text='<%# Container.DataItem("VehicleTypeName") %>'
                                                                                        Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
                                                                                    <br />
                                                                                    <asp:Label ID="lblDailyRate" runat="server" Text='<%# Container.DataItem("DailyRate") %>'
                                                                                        Visible="False"></asp:Label>
                                                                                    <input id="HiddenVehicleTypeID" type="hidden" value='<%# Container.DataItem("VTypeID") %>'
                                                                                        name="HiddenVehicleTypeID" runat="server" />
                                                                                    <input id="HiddenRateID" type="hidden" value='<%# Container.DataItem("RateID") %>'
                                                                                        name="HiddenRateID" runat="server" />
                                                                                </div>
                                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                                            <ControlButtons LeftButtonID="img_left" RightButtonID="img_right" />
                                                                        </telerik:RadRotator>
```

and I got this Exception:

```
No default member found for type 'VB$AnonymousType_0(Of Object,Object,Object,Object,Object)'. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.MissingMemberException: No default member found for type 'VB$AnonymousType_0(Of Object,Object,Object,Object,Object)'.
```

I don't know whats up ?

Any help please.

**Thanks for who tried to solve this 
but I got solution:**

using `'<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ImageURL")  %>'`

instead of `'<%# Container.DataItem("RateID") %>'`

Thanks,

Comment: If you solved it then either erase the question or answer yourself and pick your answer (just to keep SO clean).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for who tried to solve this but I got solution:

using `'<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ImageURL") %>'`

instead of `'<%# Container.DataItem("RateID") %>'`

Thanks,